# Unable to locate Xpath for dynamic text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm writing some Selenium UI automation tests and I'm currently working on a section where multiple validation messages can appear depending on the response from source system. I have several different messages to trigger.

Every time the error message is shown on the UI it will sit in the following element but the text string changes each time depending on what the message is while the id and class remain the same:

```
<span id="lblErrorText" class="validationError">
    "My error message will appear here"
</span>
```

In my page object class I am defining my fields before I use them in a method. So I have the following:

```
By errorMessage  = By.xpath("//span[@class='validationError']");
```

I then use errorMessage in a method to return it as a boolean to enable me to assert against. As follows:

```
public boolean getInvalidRefNumberErrorMessage(){
    return driver.findElements(errorMessage).contains("My error message will");
}
```

But every time I run my test I see that method getInvalidRefNumberErrorMessage is returning a FALSE.

I've tried using the id instead but no luck. I've never had to validate a dynamic message before so I'm a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your code has some wrong places if they are not copy/paste mistake.

1. Should use `findElement`, not `findElements` which return a `List`.
2. Should call `getText()` to return the message content as `String`, then call `String.contains()`

   ```
   public boolean getInvalidRefNumberErrorMessage(){
       return driver.findElement(errorMessage).getText()
                    .contains("My error message will");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So my locator was right all along. I didnt even think to check the method. Silly me! Still learning.